# Why is $(f_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ convergent on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

We have :

> $$f_n=\int_{1}^{n}{(1-\frac{x}{n})^{n}}  \cdot  \frac{1}{x} \, dx$$

$(f_{n})_{n\geq 1}$  is monotone increasing

Let :

$$u_n = \int_{1}^{n}{(\frac{e^{-x}}{x})}$$

> $$(f_{n})_{n\geq 1} \leq (u_{n})_{n\geq 1} < \infty \tag1$$

Can someone explain me (1) , thanks in advance

Comment: There shouldn't be an exponent $n$ in the definition of $u_n$.

Comment: Yes sorry , it's edited

Comment: Do you know that $(1+x/n)ˆn \rightarrow eˆx$ as $n$ tends to infinity, for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: No I didn't but now I do , thanks

Comment: Is there a proof , even if I trust you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. for every $x\geq 1$, and every $n\geq 1$, you have
   $$
   0 \leq \left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n \leq e^{-x}
   $$
   do you agree?
2. From there, we have that for every $x\geq 1$, and every $n\geq 1$
   $$
   0 \leq \frac{1}{x}\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n \leq \frac{e^{-x}}{x}
   $$
3. From there, we have by monotonicity of integrals
   $$
   0 \leq \int_{1}^n\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\frac{dx}{x} \leq \int_{1}^n \frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx
   $$
4. From there, we, since $\frac{e^{-x}}{x} \geq 0$ for all $x>0$ (and again monotonicity of the integral), 
   $$
   0 \leq \int_{1}^n\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\frac{dx}{x} \leq \int_{1}^n \frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx + \int_{n}^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx = \int_{1}^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx < \infty
   $$
   the last inequality because $\frac{e^{-x}}{x}$ is integrable on $[1,\infty)$.

We just showed that, for all $n\geq 1$, 
$$
0 \leq f_n \leq u_n < \infty
$$
as desired.